# Iterate along piped ids on shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have an output from pipe `|` given by a row-sequence of ids below: It iterates along processes and finds those attached to port `5432`.

`echo "$(lsof -i ":5432" | awk '{ print $2 }' | awk 'NR>1' | uniq -u)"`

The next step in my pipeline is to kill these processes by their ids. How can I?

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Comment: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I want to use its output as an iterator.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto what Kamil meant is that is *redundant* to use `echo` in this case, you can remove it and run the commands without `$()`. Regarding your question, I assume you can pipe all those pipes to `xargs kill -9` (but maybe you will need to use sudo or running with root). For now, I cannot test it that and be sure if that will work.

Comment: I see. I always forget this command `xargs`